# How to get cache-control max-age value from cUrl in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, cache-control

How to get cache-control: max-age value from cURL in PHP?

I have:

```
$this->get_headers_from_curl_response(curl_exec($this->curl));
```

Is there a parameter to cURL that would return only `max-age` value?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229245/use-curl-to-get-http-header-and-save-to-variable (same question, other variable)

Comment: I donno much about regular expressions so even after I get i.e. 'max-age=number, private' from the headers array I don't know how to extract the number part form it

Comment: Great a down voter. Maybe your grace would like to share why you honored me with downvote? cURL has many options and flags, is it so far fetched to thing that maybe one of them would give me max-age value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it very simple (not tested, but should work):

```
$headers = $this->get_headers_from_curl_response(curl_exec($this->curl));
$headers = explode("max-age=", $headers);
$headers = explode("\n", $headers[1]);

$max_age = trim($headers[0]);
```

Comment: $headers = explode("max-age=", $cacheControl);
      if (strpos($headers[1], ',') !== FALSE)
      {
//                     $headers[1] == '754, private';
         $headers = explode(',', $headers[1]);
      }
      else
      {
//                     $headers[1] == '754';
         $headers = explode('\n', $headers[1]);
      }
      return $max_age = trim($headers[0]);